# Материал в Unity выглядит несколько странно

Tags: unity3d

Странно ведёт себя редактор Unity на компьютере.

При создании материала, все настройки по умолчанию, единственное что задано - цвет.

В итоге в редакторе, да и в игре материал выглядит странно:

[image: Внешний вид Plane с материалом]

Да и сам материал в миниатюре выглядит неестественно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На что грешить? На видеокарту? Или как-то можно исправить эту неприятность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уберите галочку в самом низу настроек в материале

Comment: Спасибо. Странно что на другой машине такой проблемы небыло